# При парсинге определенной страницы стим, не удается вывести название предмета

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, steam

Хотел сделать парсинг страницы стим, для примера взял эту: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case. И тут же возникла такая проблема, когда я захотел вытянуть из нее название кейса, тоесть: Dreams & Nightmares Case, у меня ничего не получилось. Запрос его просто не видит, хотя в коде страницы, он точно есть. Как быть?

Мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import csv

host = 'https://steamcommunity.com/'
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case'
Headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
}

def get(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=Headers, params=params)
    return r
def get_name(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
    items =soup.find_all('div', class_='market_listing_iteminfo')
    name = []

    for item in items:
        name.append(
            {
                'name': item.find('div', class_='item_desc_description').find('h1').text
            }
        )
    return name
html = get(url)
print(get_name(html.text))
```

Comment: Сайт динамический используйте селениум или requests_html

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли, воспользовался селениумом, теперь название выводится)